# read a text file into a struct

Tags: c, struct, printing, readfile

is this the correct way to read a file into a struct?
i ve tried doing test prints but nothing prints out?
when i run and compile the program, there's no errors or set faults.

```
`int main(){
FILE* f;
linkedList* list = NULL;
house* house;

f = fopen("house.txt", "r");

list = createLinkedList();
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: File could not be opened.\n");
}  
while (!EOF)
{
    fscanf(f, "%d", &house->price);
    fscanf(f, "%d", &house->bed);
    fscanf(f, "%d", &house->bath);

    insertStart(list, character);
    printf("%d test data %d %d", house->bed, house->price, house->bath);
}
fclose(f);
freeLinkedList(list);
return 0;`
```

Comment: `while (!EOF)`?? Suggest you do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and it will clearly show your loop is not entered. You should do that before posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: `house` is an uninitialized pointer so using it is undefined behavior. What is the format of your file? Something like `while (fscanf(f, "%d%d%d", &house->price, &house->bed, &house->bath) == 3) { ... }` would probably be better.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `house* house` but didn't create actual object. Your pointer is dangling, so most likely your program is writing to and printing from undefined memory.

Comment: can you explain how to create an object in c

Comment: a) `house h;` - to create object on the stack, then access its members via `.`, like `house.price`. b) `house *h = (house*)malloc(sizeof(house));` - to create on the heap. Variant _a_ or _b_ depends on your needs and this is out of the scope of this topic.